# How to update recursive entities in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Actually I want to update an `entity` that contain a `collection` of another entity like this:

```
@Data
public class School{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   ...

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        mappedBy = "tournee",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   private List<Student> students = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
@Data
public class Student{
   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Integer id;

   ...

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SCHOOL")
   private School school;
}
```

but it shows me `stack overflow error`!

*what is stack overflow error? and how can I resolve it?*

**this is my update function**

```
@PutMapping("/update/{code}")
ResponseEntity<SchoolResponse> updateSchool(@RequestBody SchoolRequest 
                                 request,@PathVariable String code){
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    SchoolDto schoolDto = schoolService.getSchoolByCode(code);
    schoolDto = modelMapper.map(request,SchoolDto.class);
    service.update(schoolDto);
}
```

I think that there is someting missing in my entities,
it shows me that there is an infinity recursive loop between school and student entities

***Update***
this is my service:

```
@Override
public SchoolDto updateSchool(SchoolDto school Dto) {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    School school = modelMapper.map(school Dto,School.class);
    School updatedSchool = schoolRepository.save(school );
    return modelMapper.map(updatedSchool,SchoolDto.class);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the service code as well as the stacktrace you are getting/

Comment: It's probably your modelMapper which is triggering your infinite loop but without the complete stacktrace we can't be sure.

Comment: @Pilpo ModelMapper it's a famous library this is its link http://modelmapper.org/